# Getting an "query did not return a unique result" error. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a db with various tables and stuff and I use a rather large SQL query that gathers values from all the tables and sorts it so I can easily export the result as CSV.

I created a stored procedure via heidisql to trigger the query via Java.
To do that I've decided to use the repository of the table that only stores the name of the last user that clicked on a button + the timestamp of that action because I want to avoid creating a new entity.

When I execute the query manually I get a correct result with 155 lines. But when I click on the button it throws an error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 155
```

The 155 is fine. What did I do wrong? And what do I have to change to make it work?

Here's a little overview of it:

```
@Repository
public interface LogReportRepository extends JpaRepository<LogReport, Long>, Serializable {
    
        @Query(value = "CALL FORMAT_REPORT_DATA(:vonMonatParam,:bisMonatParam,:aggregationThresholdParam,:teamParam);", nativeQuery = true)
        ResultSet formatReportData(@Param("vonMonatParam") LocalDateTime fromMonth,
                                   @Param("bisMonatParam") LocalDateTime untilMonth,
                                   @Param("aggregationThresholdParam") int aggregationThreshold,
                                   @Param("teamParam") int team);
    }
```

- 

```
@Service
public class LogReportImpl implements LogReportService {

    @Autowired
    LogReportRepository logReportRepository;


    @Override
    public ResultSet formatReportData(LocalDateTime fromMonth, LocalDateTime untilMonth, int aggregationThreshold, int team) {
        return logReportRepository.formatReportData(fromMonth,untilMonth,aggregationThreshold,team);
    }
}
```

- 

```
public interface LogReportService {
    
    ResultSet formatReportData(LocalDateTime fromMonth, LocalDateTime untilMonth, int aggregationThreshold, int team);
}
```

- 

I made a test website with wicket and put it behind a button.
Here's the class for the button:

```
public class FormatButton extends Button {

    @SpringBean
    public LogReportService logReportService;

    public FormatButton(String id, IModel<String> model) {
        super(id, model);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubmit() {
        LocalDateTime fromMonth = LocalDateTime.of(2022,6,30,23,59,0);
        LocalDateTime untilMonth = LocalDateTime.of(2022,8,1,0,0,0);
        int aggregationThreshold = 37;
        int team = 1;

        ResultSet resultSet = logReportService.formatReportData(fromMonth,untilMonth,aggregationThreshold,team);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that Spring Data is expecting a single result and not 155.

I thinks the problem is the signature of `formatReportData` doesn't return a collection. If `ResultSet` is an entity or a DTO, it should be:

```
@Query(...)
List<ResultSet> formatReportData(...);
```

Alternatively, you can use the more generic:

```
@Query(...)
List<Object[]> formatReportData(...);
```

Comment: It's an interface. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Comment: I tried using List<ResultSet> but when I tried to access single items in the list using the interfaces method, it always returned the same error: basically saying the used method is not an accessor.

Comment: You cannot use any interface, you need to use one that matches the values in the select clause. There are several examples in the [Spring Data JPA reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)